# Combining 2 sets of JSON

Tags: javascript

I have this existing json in a variable (data):

```
0:
  data_name: "data1"
1:
  data_name: "data2"
2:
  data_name: "data3"
3:
  data_name: "data4"
```

And now i want to add these inside the data variable:

```
0:
  data_name: "test1"
1:
  data_name: "test2"
2:
  data_name: "test3"
3:
  data_name: "test4"
```

How do i do this? This is my desired output:

```
0:
  data_name: "data1"
1:
  data_name: "data2"
2:
  data_name: "data3"
3:
  data_name: "data4"
4:
  data_name: "test1"
5:
  data_name: "test2"
6:
  data_name: "test3"
7:
  data_name: "test4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution you are expecting but I will say , you should always first try out and  if there is some issue you should reach out to the community and also show what you tried.

```js
var arr1 = [{data_name:"data1"},{data_name:"data2"},{data_name:"data3"},{data_name:"data4"}];

var arr2 = [{data_name:"test1"},{data_name:"test2"},{data_name:"test3"},{data_name:"test4"}];

console.log([...arr1,...arr2]);
```